# Rate limiting all observables by default

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way in knockout.js to rate limit all observables by default?

I'd like to not have to `extend` all my observables one by one.

Comment: would the rate limit be a global setting or adjustable?

Comment: You really probably shouldn't be doing this unless you really know what you're doing or have a very limited application of observables.  Because rate limiting all of them will mean dependencies will trigger in random order and your logic could work sometimes but break at other times.  Also you'd mess with anything that also uses observable.  Just be careful when doing crazy things like this.

Comment: This might be a task that my plugin [knockout-deferred-updates](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates) is suited for. We're also in the process of providing similar functionality for the next version of Knockout.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function to use instead of ko.observable. I do this just to save typing, myself:`var KOB = ko.observable;`

For your case, it would be (something like):

```
var KOB = function (value) {
    return ko.observable(value).extend({rateLimit:500});
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Monkey see, monkey do: monkey patch!

But first, let me say that AFAIK there is no way to do what you want with a Knockout feature; there is no global setting (anything like `ko.globalSettings["defaultRateLimit"]`) to set default rate limits for all future observables.

Nonetheless, here's a way to monkey patch Knockout in a straightforward way to do exactly as you ask. However, I'd consider this a rather late/last resort: with monkey patching you never know how it'll affect future releases of a framework. Also, this will irrevocably change `ko.observable` so that it does what you ask, no exceptions.

```js
(function() {
  var originalObservableFn = ko.observable;
  ko.observable = function(x) {
    return originalObservableFn(x).extend({rateLimit: 1500});
  }
})();

var vm = {
  myValue: ko.observable("initial value")
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Change value here: <input data-bind="textInput: myValue" autofocus /><br />
Read only version: <span data-bind="text: myValue"></span>
```

For a more scoped solution I'd recommend [@RoyJ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30222498/419956) where you create a new shorthand function to do what you want. It allows you quite a bit more control, which is great because I can't quite imagine any practical production scenario where you want *all* observables rateLimited, not in the least because it makes unit testing them quite a bit harder as updates become asynchronous.

A final option of course would be to fork Knockout itself, which is easy as it's [source is available on GitHub](https://github.com/knockout/knockout).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function on `ko.observable` that would add some syntactical sugar to your code. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html

so instead of writing
`ko.observable(value).extend({rateLimit: 500})`

it could be possible to write
`ko.observable(value).limit(500)`

I havent tested this yet but would be worth exploring this or possibly a custom binding `data-bind="rateLimitValue: fullName"`